# Error: Cannot find module './lib/constants'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind

Esta mañana he intentado abrir mi proyecto con yarn start pero esto fue lo que sucedió:

```
yarn run v1.22.10
$ craco start
(node:2720) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\react-cars-app\node_modules\postcss-safe-parser\node_modules\postcss\package.json.
Update this package.json to use a subpath pattern like "./*".     
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was 
created)
C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\react-cars-app\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './lib/constants'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\react-cars-app\node_modules\chokidar\index.js
- C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\react-cars-app\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js
- C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\react-cars-app\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
- C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\react-cars-app\node_modules\@craco\craco\lib\cra.js
- C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\react-cars-app\node_modules\@craco\craco\scripts\start.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:940:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:773:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)  
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\react-cars-app\node_modules\chokidar\index.js:52:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14) 
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)      
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:828:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19) {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Administrador\\Desktop\\react-cars-app\\node_modules\\chokidar\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Administrador\\Desktop\\react-cars-app\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\lib\\Server.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Administrador\\Desktop\\react-cars-app\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\scripts\\start.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Administrador\\Desktop\\react-cars-app\\node_modules\\@craco\\craco\\lib\\cra.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Administrador\\Desktop\\react-cars-app\\node_modules\\@craco\\craco\\scripts\\start.js'
  ]
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Pensaba que el problema venía de craco.js (un modulo que anula la configuración de postcss y permite configurar tailwind) así que revisé mi configuracion del archivo de craco.js así como el de tailwind pero me daba el mismo error, estos son los pasos que he seguido -> [Link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app)

También comprobé que cada ruta del stack existiera pero el error persiste. Así que he deducido que esto se debe a un modulo faltante pero no sé realmente qué hacer o cómo instalarlo.

Este es mi package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-cars-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.1.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/postcss-safe-parser": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.7",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-responsive": "^8.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "twin.macro": "^2.5.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.10",
    "autoprefixer": "^9",
    "postcss": "^7",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat"
  }
}
```

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ELH8CT4J0A&list=WL&index=10&t=1553s

Comment: Has revisado la carpeta lib?

Comment: No pude encontrarlo